# File upload in Symfony and Windows user permission

Tags: php, windows, symfony, file-upload

I have an intranet website built using Symfony 3, hosted on IIS (Windows Server 2012) and users authenticate against an LDAP server to access the service.

I implemented file upload using http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html as reference.
I have an upload directory as defined in my config.yml, which is **web/uploads/files**. I gave read/write/execute permission to that directory for **Domain Users** (all users are in this group). However, each time a user uploads a new file, the right permissions are not set so my user is not able to view the file. When I set the permission manually on the newly uploaded file, my user can view it.

Is there a way to programatically set group (from LDAP) rights on uploaded files or a way to configure windows folder permissions to avoid fixing each time the issue manually ?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Any code that let us know what you've done? Any error message?

Comment: Hello, the error message given **by IIS** is the following : **HTTP Error 500.50 – URL Rewrite Module Error. Module RewriteModule Notification BeginRequest Handler StaticFile Error Code 0x80070005** This is when the user tries to open the uploaded file, before changing manually the file's permissions. As I described, changing the file's permission makes the error disappear.

The code for uploading files is just the same as the Symfony cookbook symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html. I'm doing exactly as it is shown and it's working.

Comment: Then if it's a permission issue (which I don't think since you're able to upload the file) maybe you should `chmod|chown` the file after it gets uploaded. If I were you I would double check the Apache rules since something seems not to be right there don't know for sure

Comment: Hello, I am now trying a solution using cacls (as I stated, I am working on IIS), hoping to work something out.